# Validator method not found 

Tags: validation, jsf-2

I am writing a JSF page, where user can change his password. I based my solution on the code example from JavaServer Faces (3rd edition) book by David Geary and Cay S. Horstmann. Here is my code:

```
<h:inputText id="oldPassword" required="true"
    validator="#{accountBean.validateOldPassword}">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="oldPasswordError" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="oldPassword" id="oldPasswordError" style="color: red" />
```

Part of *AccountBean.java*:

```
@Named("accountBean")
@SessionScoped
public class AccountBean implements Serializable {
    private String login;
    private String password;

    (...)
    public void validateOldPassword(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (!(((String)value).equals(password)))
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Invalid password"));
    }
}
```

Now, when I deploy this into JBoss AS 7.0.2 and try to use I get such error rendered near old password field:

```
/changePassword.xhtml @28,54 validator="#{accountBean.validateOldPassword}": Method not found: pl.edu.pw.mini.smartdialer.presentation.AccountBean@d1ff44.validateOldPassword(javax.faces.context.FacesContext, javax.faces.component.UIComponent, java.lang.Object)
```

It claims that method cannot be found, why?
This is nearly copy/paste from the book and still not working.
I have no idea where to find a bug. Could you help me?

Comment: Looks fine. Sure that you did properly rebuild/redeploy the WAR and eventually restart the server (or the server is by itself properly supporting the auto-hotdeploy)? The old class without the method might still be in the server's work folder. If that doesn't solve it, then to eliminate possible CDI noise, try `@ManagedBean @SessionScoped` (or better, `@ViewScoped`) from the `javax.faces.bean` package instead.

Comment: Any feedback? I saw you coming online several times the past 7 hours. If you don't give any feedback, how are we supposed to answer this question? I also peeked around in your question history and saw that you've basically a problem with CDI in general; that it does not seem to work in any case. So, once again, to exclude the one and other, please replace the CDI annotations by JSF annotations and retry. If that works in all circumstances, then the definite answer to your current and possibly all other problems should be straightforward enough.

Comment: For now, I resigned from CDI annotations. I use `@ManagedBean` and `@ManagedProperty` annotations with success, so I think it's not time for me to use CDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, the CDI annotations seem to not work at all.

In order to get them to work, you need to drop a `beans.xml` file in `/WEB-INF` folder. That file can be left empty. Just the presence of the file with exactly that name in exactly that location is sufficient for the container to start scanning for classes with CDI annotations.

If those classes are inside a JAR file which is in turn included in `/WEB-INF/lib`, then you should instead drop that file in `/META-INF` folder of the JAR.

This is done so to avoid unnecessary scanning for annotations during container's startup. Scanning the *entire* classpath for annotations is a relatively expensive job which may slow down container's startup. That's why you need the `beans.xml` file in order to trigger it on a per-WAR and per-JAR basis. The same construct is by the way also applied by JSF with `faces-config.xml`. If that file is absent in WAR or JAR, then JSF won't scan for JSF-specific annotations inside WAR or JAR as well.